# Remote control from one iDevice to another iDevice

Tags: iphone, ipad, remote-control

So what I'm trying to achieve is using my iPad 2 as a media player and I want to be able to control it from my iPhone so I can leave it playing music/movies and I can control the volume, play and pause it without having to manipulate the iPad.
Is this possible? Is there any app that allows to control an iDevice from another iDevice? Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [Tunes Remote](http://tunesremote.com/) which looks like it fits perfectly and it can be downloaded from the App Store. Does anybody know it?

Comment: No, that app controls a *computer* running iTunes, not another iOS device.

Comment: @daviesgeek you sure? This is what I read in the description: "Note: to control iTunes on your Desktop you would want to use the Apple 'Remote' App. Tunes Remote works the other way around: it lets you control your iPod Touch or iPhone."

Comment: Oh. I read your link as "iTunes Remote" Haha! Sorry 'bout that!